# Check for NULL or empty '' in function?

Tags: php, null

I'm running the following function and want to check if a value is NULL or '', but it seems to react the same for both. This prints `C1C2`. How can I get it to print `B1C1C2`? Should I use `isset()` somehow?

```
function title($a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL) {
    if( $a != NULL )
    {
        echo 'A1';
        if( $a != '' )
        {
            echo 'A2';
        }
    }
    if( $b != NULL )
    {
        echo 'B1';
        if( $b != '' )
        {
            echo 'B2';
        }
    }
    if( $c != NULL )
    {
        echo 'C1';
        if( $c != '' )
        {
            echo 'C2';
        }
    }
}

title(NULL, '', 'C');
```

Comment: Just use `!isnull($a)` or `!empty($a)`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton maybe you meant `is_null()`

Comment: @JulianDavid That I did, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just check for the value of the variable you will get true whether `null` or an empty string (`''`):

```
null == ''; // 1 (true)
```

You also need to check for type:

```
null === ''; // (false)
```

---

So instead of:

```
if( $a != NULL )
```

Run:

```
if( $a !== NULL )
```

Which will also check for type; `''` is a `string` - not `null` type.

---

Rearranged function:

```
function title($a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL) {
    if( $a !== NULL )
    {
        echo 'A1';
        if( $a !== '' )
        {
            echo 'A2';
        }
    }
    if( $b !== NULL )
    {
        echo 'B1';
        if( $b !== '' )
        {
            echo 'B2';
        }
    }
    if( $c !== NULL )
    {
        echo 'C1';
        if( $c !== '' )
        {
            echo 'C2';
        }
    }
}

title(NULL, '', 'C'); // outputs: B1C1C2
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful because ...

```
if(null == 0) echo "yes"; else echo "nope"; //prints yes
if(null === 0) echo "yes"; else echo "nope"; //prints no
```

So always use triple equals (=== or !==) instead of double equals (== or !=) in order to avoid this issue.

But the most appropriate way would be to use the "is_null()" PHP builtin function which returns true or false.

```
if(is_null(0)) echo "yes"; else echo "nope"; //prints nope
```

So we have ...

```
function title($a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL) {
    if(!is_null($a)) // using is_null builtin function
        echo 'A1';
        if($a !== '')// not !=, because 0!='' is false
            echo 'A2';
    if(!is_null($b))
        echo 'B1';
        if($b !== '')
            echo 'B2';
    if(!is_null($c))
        echo 'C1';
        if($c !== '')
            echo 'C2';
}

title(NULL, '', 'C'); // prints B1C1C2
```